# the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by an older version

Tags: security, workflow

We have a 2 step workflow i.e draft and final.

We notice the warning message below on any item when trying to edit

```
If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it has been replaced by an older version.
Version 1 will be published instead.
```

1. Do we need to worry about this warning?
2. is there any fix we could apply to stop this warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if Version 2 of your item in "final" workflow state.

This is not an error. This is a functionality of Sitecore. When the current item version you are working on does not satisfy the requirement to publish (ex: item version is not in the final workflow state, item version is set to never publish, item version have publish time set, etc), this warning will be displayed.

Comment: How would one check if an item is in "final" workflow state? How would one know if a Workflow is pending/being applied to an item in the first place